# wpf jump from one tabitem to another tabitem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

In my project, I use a tabcontrol for navigation. The tabcontrol has three tabitem, the second tabitem is a usercontrol which contains a datagrid and the third tabitem contains a canvas. And when I double click a row in datagrid, I want UI jump to the third tabitem and draw the selected row in canvas. How can I achieve this? thanks!
main window xaml as follow:

```
<Window x:Class="PCClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PCClient"        
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:PCClient.ViewModels"        
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PCClient.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="600">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel></viewModel:MainViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="数据采集" Padding="5">
            <controls:ECGImportControl DataContext="{Binding Children[0]}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="数据管理" Padding="5">
            <controls:ECGImportRecordsControl DataContext="{Binding Children[1]}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="ECG全屏" Padding="5">
            <Grid>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <ScrollBar Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                    <Canvas Background="AliceBlue"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and usercontrol as follow:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PCClient.Controls.ECGImportRecordsControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PCClient.Controls"
         xmlns:convert="clr-namespace:PCClient.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <convert:ConvertIntToString x:Key="convertIntToString"></convert:ConvertIntToString>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Margin="5"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="查询" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ImportRecords}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImportRecord,Mode=TwoWay}"
              CanUserSortColumns="False"  CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Extended"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"  RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  EnableRowVirtualization="False" GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="姓名" Width="3*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="性别" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sex,Converter={StaticResource convertIntToString}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="硬件ID" Width="2*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="硬件类型" Width="2*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceType}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="采集开始时间" Width="6*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime,StringFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="采集结束时间" Width="6*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EndTime,StringFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="导入时间" Width="6*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UploadTime,StringFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant number of `TabItems` you can go with `IsSelected` like this:

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem IsSelected="{Binding IsFirstTabSelected,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TextBlock>First Tab</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem IsSelected="{Binding IsSecondTabSelected,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TextBlock>Second Tab</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

You can use `Triggers` and `VisualStateManager` too - instead of just bind it to your `ViewModel`.

Just make sure - you get the right event. Or overwrite the "blocking" events - by setting `e.Handled` in your event-methods to `false`. Maybe you go with `IsHitTestVisible=false` on the `FrameworkElements` that block your events. Your question is a bit broad.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. The question is I have no idea about how can I set the tabcontrol state inside my usercontrol because I cannot get the MainViewModel inside my usercontrol. Can I just binding a  property from Children[1] to the IsSelected of tabtiem 3?